Error deploying Cloud Function with Firestore trigger on Google Cloud
I'm encountering an issue while deploying a Cloud Function on Google Cloud. The function is triggered by document creation in a Firestore collection named "users" in Firebase. The deployment process appears to be successful, but when I test the function, I encounter an error. Additionally, manually creating a document in the "users" collection in Firebase does not trigger the function as expected.
I've configured the Cloud Function to be triggered by Firestore events using the on_document_created method from the firebase_functions library in Python. However, when an event occurs, the function fails with an error, and I'm unsure of how to proceed with debugging.
Any insights or suggestions on how to troubleshoot and resolve this issue would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!
My Cloud Function Python main.py code :
# Welcome to Cloud Functions for Firebase for Python!
# To get started, simply uncomment the below code or create your own.
# Deploy with `firebase deploy`

import pandas as pd
from firebase_admin import firestore
from firebase_functions import firestore_fn
from firebase_admin import initialize_app
import json
import os 
import glob
import openai
from openai import OpenAI
from google.cloud import storage
from io import BytesIO

# Initialize Firebase app
initialize_app()

# Définir votre clé d'API OpenAI
api_key = os.getenv('OPENAI_API_KEY')

# Définir le projet 
my_project = 'safeplace-2e1b4'

@firestore_fn.on_document_created(document="users/{doc_id}")
def upload_csv_to_firestore_2(event: firestore_fn.Event[firestore_fn.DocumentSnapshot]):

    try:
        # Récupération document nouvel user
        document_data = event.data.to_dict()
        social_networks = document_data['selected_social_networks']
        user_id = document_data['uid']

        bucket_name = "gcf-v2-uploads-953028720515-us-central1"
        file_name = "export.csv"
        
        df_result_filter = download_file_from_storage(bucket_name, file_name)
        df_result_filter = df_result_filter.drop(columns='Unnamed: 0')

        # Convert DataFrame to dictionary
        data_dict = df_result_filter.to_dict(orient='records')
        
        # Upload data to Firestore collection
        db = firestore.client()
         # Créer une référence à la collection principale 'messages'
        messages_collection_ref = db.collection('messages')
        # Créer une référence à une sous-collection avec l'ID de l'utilisateur
        user_messages_collection_ref = messages_collection_ref.document(user_id).collection('messages')
        
        for record in data_dict:
            # Créer une référence à un nouveau document dans la sous-collection de l'utilisateur
            doc_ref = user_messages_collection_ref.document()
            # Ajouter le document avec les données
            doc_ref.set(record)

        print("CSV data uploaded to Firestore collection successfully.")

        openai_to_firestore(user_id,df_result_filter)

    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error during CSV upload: {e}")

    return "Messages analysed and uploaded to Firestore collection successfully."

def openai_to_firestore(user_id,df_result_filter):

    try:
        predictions_df = openai_model(df_result_filter,api_key)
        predictions_df = predictions_df.drop_duplicates(subset=['conv_id'], keep='first')
        predictions_df = predictions_df.reset_index(drop=True)
        predictions_df = predictions_df.rename(columns={"label": "prediction"})
        
        # Convert DataFrame to dictionary
        data_dict = predictions_df.to_dict(orient='records')
        
        # Upload data to Firestore collection
        db = firestore.client()
         # Créer une référence à la collection principale 'messages'
        messages_collection_ref = db.collection('analysed_messages')
        # Créer une référence à une sous-collection avec l'ID de l'utilisateur
        user_messages_collection_ref = messages_collection_ref.document(user_id).collection('analysed_messages')
        
        for record in data_dict:
            # Créer une référence à un nouveau document dans la sous-collection de l'utilisateur
            doc_ref = user_messages_collection_ref.document()
            # Ajouter le document avec les données
            doc_ref.set(record)

        print("Messages analysed and uploaded successfully.")

    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error during OpenAI processing: {e}")


def openai_model(df,api_key):
    
    # Vérifier si la clé API est disponible
    if api_key is None:
        raise ValueError("La clé API OpenAI n'a pas été trouvée dans les variables d'environnement.")

    client = OpenAI(api_key=api_key)
    
    df = df.drop(columns={'Unnamed: 0'})
    conversations = df.groupby('Participant_ID')

    # Liste des étiquettes à prédire
    labels = ['Not_cyberbullying','Hate', 'Insult', 'Obscene', 'Racism', 'Ethnicity', 'Religion', 'Threat', 'Toxic', 'Severe-Toxic', 'Pedophile', 'Other_cyberbullying']
    # Dictionnaire pour stocker les prédictions et les scores
    predictions = {'conv_id': [], 'label': [], 'score': []}

    # Parcourir chaque conversation
    for conv_id, conv_messages in conversations:
        Messages = []
        # Afficher les messages de la conversation
        for index, row in conv_messages.iterrows():
            sender = row['Sender']
            recipient = row['Receiver']
            message_content = row['Content']
            message_date = row['Timestamp']

            Messages.append(f"Sender: {sender}, Recipient: {recipient}, Content: {message_content}, Date: {message_date}")

        messages = ',\n'.join(Messages)   

        # Faire la requête à l'API GPT
        response = client.chat.completions.create(
            model="gpt-3.5-turbo",
            messages=[
            {
                "role": "system",
                "content": "You will receive a list of messages from the same conversation, and your objective is to determine whether the conversation's sentiment is cyberbullying or not."
            },
            {
                "role": "user",
                "content": f"Classify the following conversation into one of the following categories: {' | '.join(labels)}.\n\n{messages}\n\nFor each prediction, please provide a reliability score between 0 and 100%. Please format your response as follows: the prediction, the score. No explanation needed.\n"
            }
            ],
            temperature=0.7,
            max_tokens=64,
            top_p=0.3
        )
            
        # Extraire les prédictions et les scores de fiabilité
        choices = response.choices

        for choice in choices:
            
            print(choice)
            
            prediction = choice.message.content.split(',')[0]
            
            # Vérifier s'il y a des scores de fiabilité disponibles
            if len(choice.message.content.split(',')) > 1:
                # Les scores de fiabilité sont dans les logprobs
                score = choice.message.content.split(',')[1]
                
            else:
                # Aucun score de fiabilité disponible
                score = None
                
            # Stocker les résultats dans le dictionnaire
            predictions['conv_id'].append(conv_id.split('_')[-1])
            predictions['label'].append(prediction)
            predictions['score'].append(score)   

    # Créer un DataFrame à partir du dictionnaire de prédictions
    predictions_df = pd.DataFrame(predictions)

    return predictions_df

def download_file_from_storage(bucket_name, file_name):
    # Initialize Cloud Storage client
    storage_client = storage.Client(project=my_project)

    # Get bucket
    bucket = storage_client.bucket(bucket_name)

    # Get blob (file) from bucket
    blob = bucket.blob(file_name)

    # Download file as bytes
    file_content = blob.download_as_string()

    # Convert bytes to DataFrame
    df = pd.read_csv(BytesIO(file_content))

    return df

My requierements.txt file :
firebase-functions
pandas
firebase-admin
openai
google-cloud

deployment succeed
test error
The Test Error :
[5:49:48 PM] - [2024-04-21 15:49:48,099] ERROR in app: Exception on / [POST]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.10/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1473, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.10/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 882, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.10/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 880, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.10/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 865, in dispatch_request
    return self.ensure_sync(self.view_functions[rule.endpoint])(**view_args)  # type: ignore[no-any-return]
  File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.10/site-packages/functions_framework/__init__.py", line 178, in view_func
    function(event)
  File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.10/site-packages/firebase_functions/firestore_fn.py", line 446, in on_document_created_wrapped
    return _firestore_endpoint_handler(
  File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.10/site-packages/firebase_functions/firestore_fn.py", line 121, in _firestore_endpoint_handler
    _firestore.DocumentEventData.from_json(event_data))
  File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.10/site-packages/proto/message.py", line 428, in from_json
    Parse(payload, instance._pb, ignore_unknown_fields=ignore_unknown_fields)
  File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.10/site-packages/google/protobuf/json_format.py", line 416, in Parse
    text = text.decode('utf-8')
AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'decode'

